# Как в jquery просуммировать значения массива с одинаковыми датами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу помочь с получением данных из массива.

Есть массив, к примеру:

Дата, значение1, значение2, Значение3, Значение4
2021-10-21, 1, 1, 1, 1
2021-10-21, 1, 1, 1, 1
2021-10-22, 1, 1, 1, 1
2021-10-22, 1, 1, 1, 1
2021-10-23, 1, 1, 1, 1

Я хочу пройтись циклом по этому массиву выбрать все значения с одинаковыми датами и просуммировать их и вывести полученный результат в HTML.

По итогу должно получиться

2021-10-21, 2, 2, 2, 2
2021-10-22, 2, 2, 2, 2
2021-10-23, 1, 1, 1, 1

Сейчас я получаю сумму всех значений из БД кодом:

Массив:

```
var массив = JSON.parse(data)

//По итогу массив получается если в консоль вывести:

0: ""
1: {id: "1", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-18", значение1: "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"}
2: {id: "2", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-18", значение1: "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"}
3: {id: "3", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-19", значение1: "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"}


$.each(массив, function(index,value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < value["active"].length; i++) {
        var Дата = value["Дата"];
        var Значение1 += value["Значение1"];
        var Значение2 += value["Значение2"];
        var Значение3 += value["Значение3"];
        var Значение4 += value["Значение3"];
    }

    $(".text").append(
        '<td>'+Дата+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+Значение1+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+Значение2+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+Значение3+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+Значение4+'</td>'
    );
}
```

Но это выводит каждую дату отдельно и не правильно суммирует значения у строк.

Comment: В коде вoпроса опечатка (`"Значение3"` там где предполагается `"Значение4"`), возможно баг в этом. Для получения ответов с кодом, желательно добавить [repro].

Comment: сложите суммарные значения в объект, где ключами будут даты. Идете по исходному массиву, берете дату. Если ее нет еще в объекте, то добавляете этот массив с этим ключом. идете дальше. Снова эта дата - приплюсовываете к значиям в объекте. После того как цикл завершен - проходите по ключам объекта и выводите.

Comment: @teran
А можете подсказать, как это должно выглядеть по итогу в коде?
Не очень понимаю, что должно получиться

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подсчета по ключу удобно использовать ассоциативные массивы (во всех языках программирования). Добавил в ваш код промежуточную переменную ht, используемую для подсчета суммы для каждой даты.

```js
var data = `{
"0": "",
"1": {"id": "1", "id2": "1", "date": "2021-10-18", "значение1": "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"},
"2": {"id": "2", "id2": "1", "date": "2021-10-18", "значение1": "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"},
"3": {"id": "3", "id2": "1", "date": "2021-10-19", "значение1": "1", "значение2": "1", "значение3": "1", "значение4": "1"}
}`;


var массив = JSON.parse(data);

var ht = {};
$.each(массив, function(index,value) {
        var Дата = value["date"];
        if (!Дата)
          return;
        var Значение1 = parseInt(value["значение1"], 10);
        var Значение2 = parseInt(value["значение2"], 10);
        var Значение3 = parseInt(value["значение3"], 10);
        var Значение4 = parseInt(value["значение4"], 10);

    //for (var i = 0; i < value["active"].length; i++) {
        if (ht[Дата]) {
           ht[Дата]["Значение1"] += Значение1;
           ht[Дата]["Значение2"] += Значение2;
           ht[Дата]["Значение3"] += Значение3;
           ht[Дата]["Значение4"] += Значение4;
        }
        else {
           ht[Дата] = {
            "Значение1": Значение1,
            "Значение2": Значение2,
            "Значение3": Значение3,
            "Значение4": Значение4,
           }
        }
});
    for (var i in ht) {

      $(".text").append('<tr>' +
          '<td>'+i+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+ht[i]["Значение1"]+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+ht[i]["Значение2"]+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+ht[i]["Значение3"]+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+ht[i]["Значение4"]+'</td>'+
          '</tr>');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="text"></table>
```

Comment: Отличное решение всё получилось. Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    {id: "1", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-18", value1: "1", value2: "1", value3: "1", value4: "1"},
    {id: "2", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-18", value1: "1", value2: "1", value3: "1", value4: "1"},
    {id: "3", id2: "1", date: "2021-10-19", value1: "1", value2: "1", value3: "1", value4: "1"},
];

const map = {};

arr.forEach(({date, value1, value2, value3, value4, ...other}) => {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        map[date].value1 += +value1;
        map[date].value2 += +value2;
        map[date].value3 += +value3;
        map[date].value4 += +value4;
    } else map[date] = Object.assign({value1: +value1, value2: +value2, value3: +value3, value4: +value4}, other);
});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: так у меня не работает. Добавил в текст вопроса то как выглядит мой массив при выводе в консоль. Думаю из-за этого и проблема (разный вид массива), что ваш способ не сработал.

Comment: @nektovse ну так и приводили бы сразу код, в котором понятна структура данных. Исправил ответ.